# Laravel merge get() and paginate() collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How do we merge collections in laravel without loosing the pagination or how can i add data to a paginated collection?

```
...
$admins = Users::where('role', 'admin')->get();
$superUsers = Users::where('role', 'superUsers')
    ->where('fixed', '>=', 100)
    ->paginate(5);

if ($request->page == 1) {
    return $superUsers->merge($admins);
}

return $superUsers;
...
```

Comment: I would think you can just do `User::whereIn('role', ['admin', 'superUsers'])->paginate(5);`. If you're trying to do this so `admin` rows are at the beginning (on Page 1, etc.), then you'd just use some kind of sorting method.

Comment: Thanks for the response @TimLewis but I'd like them to be merged with the pagination preserved because there more conditions in the query that separates the admins from the other users.

Comment: I see. I don't think there is then. Pagination works on the premise that there is a known number of records to paginate; appending things after the fact just likely isn't going to work. See if you can refactor your query to return all records in a single call, or maybe a `UNION` query, etc., then call `->paginate()`.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis. I did ended up using union.